# Wrapping floated text within a liquid-width container

Tags: html, css

In a percentage-width container, a H2 is floated left and an image is floated right.

As the browser width is decreased, the image is pushed left towards the H2. When they meet, the logo is pushed down below the H2.

Example JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VgS8B/1/

How can I make it so that the text starts wrapping over multiple lines **before** the image drops down underneath it? Like a sort of CSS "force whitespace wrap"?

This is probably simple but my brain isn't working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary that the heading be floated left? You could left align it, remove its float, and place it below the image within the HTML to get [your desired effect](http://jsfiddle.net/XDRz9/).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VgS8B/5/

Comment: It does the job, but uses more code than the solution above. Thanks nevertheless.